# How to execute a binary added to $PATH inside WSL2 from CMD?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Inside my WSL2 environment I have `adb` added to the Path env variable. I want to invoke it directly from Windows CMD like so: `wsl adb`, but I receive the following error:

`zsh:1: command not found: adb`

It's as if it doesn't source ~/.zprofile when it runs the command and thus doesn't have the adjusted PATH variable. Any ideas how to deal with this? ZSH is the default shell inside my WSL2 environment and running `adb` from inside it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, this seems to work: `wsl zsh -ic "adb"`